# "npm run build" = "react-scripts: Permission denied"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, jenkins, npm

I'm trying to deploy my working Windows 10 Spring-Boot/React app on Ubuntu 18.04 but keep getting "react-scripts: Permission denied" error despite numerous attempts to fix. Hopefully one of you react experts can spot what I'm doing wrong.

My package.json looks like this

```
{
  "name": "medaverter-front",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "react": "^16.13.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.0",
    "react-table-6": "^6.11.0",
    "react-validation": "^3.0.7",
    "reactstrap": "^6.5.0",
    "validator": "^12.2.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

I'm logged in as root and used nvm to install node and lts. I installed nvm like this:

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.0/install.sh | bash
```

then did this:

```
nvm install node
nvm use node
nvm install --lts
nvm use --lts
```

Then I `cd` to `/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MedAverter/medaverter-front` and install `node_modules` like this:

```
npm install -g
```

and then change the permissions to 777 recursively, like this:

```
chmod -R 777 node_modules
```

I also changed all the /root/.nvm permissions to 777 recursively, like this:

```
chmod -R 777 /root/.nvm
```

I can get it build once using

```
npm run build
```

but then I run a "Build Now" from Jenkins and it fails with the same

> ```
> [[1;34mINFO[m] Running 'npm run build' in /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MedAverter/medaverter-front
> [[1;34mINFO[m] [[1;34mINFO[m] > medaverter-front@0.1.0 build /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MedAverter/medaverter-front
> [[1;34mINFO[m] > react-scripts build [[1;34mINFO[m] 
> [[1;31mERROR[m] sh: 1: **react-scripts: Permission denied**
> [[1;31mERROR[m] npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
> [[1;31mERROR[m] npm ERR! errno 126
> [[1;31mERROR[m] npm ERR! medaverter-front@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build` 
> [[1;31mERROR[m] npm ERR! Exit status 126
> ```

Then I `cd` to `/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MedAverter/medaverter-front` and run

```
npm run build
```

And also get the same error again:

> ```
> > root@ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-nyc1-01:/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MedAverter/medaverter-front#
> > npm run build
> > 
> > > medaverter-front@0.1.0 build /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MedAverter/medaverter-front
> > > react-scripts build
> > 
> > sh: 1: **react-scripts: Permission denied** npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
> > npm ERR! errno 126 npm ERR! medaverter-front@0.1.0 build:
> > `react-scripts build` npm ERR! Exit status 126
> ```

I've literally spent days trying to figure this out.  Suggestions?

Comment: Check the ubuntu user permissions you run node with

Comment: Why did you install globally and then change permissions in `node_modules`, a non-global directory? Did you try removing `-g`? Also, your chmod stuff isn't necessary, and is actually really dangerous. Please don't do that. Permission denied usually means the executable flag is not set, or it's chowned as another user and the bits aren't set for anyone other than user/group. The way you're installing modules is super weird though.

Comment: Yes, I tried it without the - g initially and couldn't get that to work.  Added the -g later attempting different solutions.  I know the final solution should not involve setting 777 privileges but I'm just trying to get something to work, then back off to the proper way later once the real solution gets revealed.  Do you know what that is?

Comment: I had encountered similar issue when I installed npm and nvm with sudo. After uninstalling and installing it back with regular user permissions fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out a solution to this problem.  It took days of effort.  First, I deleted the Jenkins project and created a new one using Pipeline, rather than Freestyle.  Then I added a Jenkinsfile with a script.  That continued to fail but now I had the flexibility to add in additional commands to handle the errors.

One new error was something about jest-worker. I ran the following command on the DigitalOcean server to get past that one:

```
yarn add jest-worker
```

Then I had the old permissions error again.  I think all these permission errors are due to user jenkins trying to run things owned by user root, even though everything had 777 permissions.  I don't understand that but here's how I got around it.  Modify the /etc/sudoers file and add the following line:

```
jenkins ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

Then modify the Jenkins file script to include recursive chmod and chown.  Here is the full script that FINALLY worked:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Checkout') {
            steps {
                echo 'Checkout...'
                sh 'sudo chmod -R 777 /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MedAverter/medaverter-front'
                checkout scm
                sh 'sudo chmod -R 777 /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MedAverter/medaverter-front'
                sh 'sudo chown -R jenkins /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MedAverter/medaverter-front'
                stash 'sources'
            }
        }
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                echo 'Build...'
                unstash 'sources'
                sh 'sudo chmod -R 777 /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MedAverter/medaverter-front'
                sh 'sudo chown -R jenkins /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MedAverter/medaverter-front'
                sh 'mvn clean package -DskipTests'
                stash 'sources'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I also had to increase the memory of the DigitalOcean droplet from 1GB to 2GB to get past another error.  If someone knows a better way to get past that frustrating permissions error, please comment.

Answer (score 105):

## Solution 1:

I think you have react-script globally installed. so try this command

```
npm install react-scripts --save
```

and then run the application again.

## Solution 2:

try this command

```
sudo chmod +x node_modules/.bin/react-scripts
```

and then run the application again.

## Solution 3;

I think your **npm** not have permission. you can try to run by sudo

```
sudo npm run build
```

and you can fix this problem like this

### Step 1:

check path of **npm** if you are using **npm** by

```
which npm
```

you will "/usr/local/bin/npm" this type of path

**OR**

check path of **yarn** if you are using **yarn** by

```
which yarn
```

you will "/usr/local/bin/npm" this type of path

### Step 2:

give permission 777 to this path and try to run project

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /usr/local/bin/npm
```

Comment: Solution 2 was it for me.

Answer (score 28):

## Solution for macOS

##### From the root of your project run:

```
chmod +x node_modules/.bin/react-scripts
```

Answer (score 9):

The following worked for me:

```
rm -rf node_modules 

npm install // or yarn install

npm start // or yarn start
```

Answer (score 7):

Instead of the default `"start": "react-scripts start"` specified in your `package.json` file, try changing it to the following and then try: `"scripts": { "start": "node ./node_modules/react-scripts/bin/react-scripts.js start" }`

Comment: Tried that but getting the same error.  Do I need to close out the PuTTY session and start a new one after making the change?

Answer (score 6):

In my case it was giving at npm run.
this is how i solved.

1. rm -rf /node_modules
2. npm i
3. npm run android

Answer (score 5):

I had modified the permissions on the folders earlier and undid the changes. I believe that is it.

I just deleted the `node_modules` folder and reinstalled the dependencies with the `yarn` command.

```sh
sudo rm -rf node_modules
yarn
yarn start
```

Answer (score 1):

1st run on terminal
**sudo chmod +x node_modules/.bin/react-scripts**

2nd run **npm start** command

Answer (score 0):

It seems you don't have the right permission to build or execute the react app,

What you could do is try changing the owner to the current user using

```
   sudo chown -R username:username /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MedAverter/medaverter-front/
```

you can check your username by typing `whoami` in the terminal this is done because the current user does not have access to to the `var` folder or anything inside it by default. Furthermore you want to change the access mode to read and execute for everyone using

```
 sudo chmod 755 /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MedAverter/medaverter-front/
```

then you can want to change to root user using

```
sudo su
```

and then build the app using

```
npm run build
```

This has worked for me when i was facing somewhat a similar problem , hopefully it works for you as well,Cheers :)

Comment: Thanks for the post.  I didn't see it until after I had already posted my solution.  There is only one user on the DigitalOcean server and that is root.  Isn't su the same as root?

Comment: `Isn't su the same as root?` Not necessarily,without additional parameters,Yes: `su` would shift to root user.su is actually the system(which has root privileges) but since root has most privileges it should work in the first place, Since the server uses `www-data` as the default user, so anything that the `www-data` can access the server can access ,you could simply replace `username` by `www-data` and skip the 3rd command and it should be all good. Anyways it seems you already solved it  so,Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

That happens because of lack of a package.json file
Just run this command and the issue will be fixed:

```
npm audit fix
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes npm need root permission. Try using sudo in the command. It resolved a similar issue for me. This might help.

```
sudo npm run build
```

Comment: is this safe to use "sudo" everywhere?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and I sole it with: version in **package.json** and `npm i -g react-scripts`

```
"react-scripts": "5.0.0"
```

It was : `"react-scripts": "5.0.1"` and I change it to `"react-scripts": "5.0.0"`

And again did `npm i`

If it's not solving issue please check versions of `react-scripts` form current version of React that you are using.