# Permission denied when running npm start

Tags: node.js, npm, frontend

I'm trying to run a node and react js project that i got from someone else and this is the error that i get.
Can someone please help me fix this?

```
cd frontend
npm start

> frontend@0.1.0 start
> react-scripts start

sh: /Users/..../...../...../frontend/node_modules/.bin/react-scripts: Permission denied
.... frontend %
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["npm run build" = "react-scripts: Permission denied"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62140265/npm-run-build-react-scripts-permission-denied)

Comment: `packages.json` has to be checked, where script start points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just run the command below in project root. You might installed it globally.

```
npm install react-scripts --save
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't have required permissions in the given directory.
You can run

```
sudo npm start
```

or update permissions for the directory

```
sudo chmod 777 -R Your_Dir/
```

Comment: `npm ERR! Missing script: "start"
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Did you mean one of these?
npm ERR!     npm star # Mark your favorite packages
npm ERR!     npm stars # View packages marked as favorites
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! To see a list of scripts, run:
npm ERR!   npm run`

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove node_modules folder and package-lock.json

```
sudo rm -rf node_modules
sudo rm package-lock.json
npm install
```